# Django Registration - Checks if a user already exists

Tags: django

The web app currently should be able to register new users. However, should a user already exists, it should redirect user to the login page with a message of "User already exists!".
The Django views:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def registerPage(request):
     form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(
                    request, 'User already exists! Try logging in.')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                raw_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(raw_password)
                user.save()
                ...
```

I filter the user by his/her username and checks if it already exists by using the `exists()` method. This doesn't seem to work though. Is there something I'm missing?

**UPDATE**
What's not working is that the check I believe is not working. Because if it successfully checks that a user exists, then it should `redirect('login')` instead of running the `else` statement.

---

**SOLUTION**
Turns out that because I'm using Django's built in CreateUserForm and is doing validation using `form.is_valid()`, hence it is already built in for Django to check whether the user already exists or not. So what I did was to just add an `else` statement after the `if form.is_valid()` and redirect my user to the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` already marked unique=True in auth/models.py so simply you can use try/catch.